# Get Value of <td> tags using contenteditable and sending them to php

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<form  method="post" action="xmpl.php" >
   <table class="tg" id="table">
   <thead>
   
     <tr>
       <td>Όνομα*</td>
        <td class="tgh" contenteditable='true' onclick="clearing(1)" name="onoma"></td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td class="tgh">Επώνυμο*</td>
       <td class="tgh" contenteditable='true' onclick="clearing(3)"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="tgh">Α.Μ.Κ.Α*</td>
       <td class="tgh" contenteditable='true' id='filled_form' onclick="clearing(5)"></td>
     </tr>                       
   </tbody>
   </table>
   <div id="login">
        <button type="submit" name="send" onclick="submited()">Εγγραφή</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And i call using the form, the xmpl.php file i have created (it contains one line,  echo $_POST['onoma'];), however it returns an error 'Notice: Undefined index: onoma in xmpl.php'

Why is that?

Comment: Just because its editable, does not mean it will be sent to the PHP code by the browser. The contents of a FORM are sent to the backend PHP code though

Comment: Is there a way to get the contents or i have to scrap it and start again?

Comment: Well you could use javascript to collect the contents of these and build an AJAX call. It really depends upon what you are actually trying to achieve